# Errors when trying to install CS:GO via Steam

Tags: steam, technical-issues, counter-strike-global-offensive

Recently i'm getting errors such as "Invalid Instalation Path" or "Disk Write Error" when i try to install CS:GO using steam. I've tried formatting my pc, re-installing steam, open it as an administrator, but no cigar.

Does anyone knows a solution for this?

Comment: When you re-installed Steam, did you delete the Steam folder as well or just "uninstall" it? If you didn't you can try deleting everything from that folder, except for the steam.exe and the SteamApps folder. Then start Steam again. You can as well try installing the game on different drive to see if that works.

Answer (score -1):

Well, this just looks like a disc problem. But i need something to b eclear: Are you using Windows 10, Mac or Linux to install this?

Try freeing up some space on your hard disc, and check to see if anyone else has had these problems.